# Applying Styles to rdl file

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there anyway to apply styles to a `.rdl` file that will be imported to `Microsoft Dynamics CRM` ?
My need is to apply a custom font to an `SSRS report` without the need to install this font to the clients machines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check this link: [http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/01/utilizing-custom-fonts-with-sql-reporting-services-ssrs-and-exporting-to-pdf/](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/01/utilizing-custom-fonts-with-sql-reporting-services-ssrs-and-exporting-to-pdf/)

Comment: Thanks Guido, appreciating your efforts

I don't need to extract the report as a PDF, I just need to run the report button in the ribbon.

Comment: I understand, but the article explains that is possible to embed the fonts only when the report is exported to PDF, when you open the report inside the browser only the fonts available on the client are used for rendering.

Comment: So there is no way to display a custom font used in SSRS report in CRM report viewer unless the font is installed on client machine ?

Comment: As far as I know is not possible, but maybe someone else will come out with a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to install the font on the client machines. The font is rendered on the server so as long as the font is installed on the server hosting the reports, it should work.

(I'm assuming you're using CRM on-premise. If you're online I think you might be out of luck)

Comment: Hi, I am using CRM on-premise. I installed Old English Text MT in Server and when I run my report on server's report configuration manager it gives me correct font. But when I run the report on web client I don't get specified font. Any sugeesions to get this work

Comment: @Mathee , Did you  found the solution? If so please share. Even I am facing the same :(